# Работа с mouseover JS на телефоне

Tags: javascript, события, mobile

Есть кнопка на которые привязанные действие 
    `addEventListener("touchstart", open_button)`
И после этого есть также событие 
    `addEventListener("mouseenter", select_section)`
После того как нажата кнопка и прости вверх должно выполниться действие, но оно не работает.
Почему?

Код

```
run_button_design[0].addEventListener("touchstart", open_button); // mousedown

run_button_section[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", select_section);

run_button_design[0].addEventListener("touchend", close_button); // mouseup

function open_button(elem){
    run_button_design[0].classList.add("rbd_hover");
    run_button_open[0].classList.add("rbo_hover");
    elem.preventDefault();
}


function select_section(elem){
    run_button_section[0].classList.add("rbs");
    // elem.preventDefault();

}


function close_button(elem){
    run_button_design[0].classList.remove("rbd_hover");
    run_button_open[0].classList.remove("rbo_hover");
    // elem.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Как вы определили, что не работает? Код нам свой покажете?

Comment: Уже добавил код

Comment: на телефонах нет события "mouseenter"

Comment: а какой есть аналог?